# MongoDB command failing

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

Sorry I'm so new to MongoDB and have been struggling to see why my simple command does not work:

My command:

```
db.baz.findAndModify(query:{name:"foo2"}, update:{$unset:{phone:""}});
```

Error message:

```
 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

And is unset the best option to remove a field data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the outer braces on your `findAndModify` parameter.

It should be:

```javascript
db.baz.findAndModify({query: {name: "foo2"}, update: {$unset: {phone: ""}}});
```

And yes, `$unset` is the right operator to remove a field from an existing doc.

Comment: Oh good catch; I know it could be a stupid syntax error! Thanks!